# Menu Item on click event not working in gtk3 + python3

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I have written a script in python3 and Gtk3, and I want it to close the window when I click on the "close" Menu Item, but when i do it nothing append. I am using Ubuntu 16.10.
This is the script:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MenuTest(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='MenuTest')

        Box=Gtk.VBox()
        self.add(Box)

        Menubar=Gtk.MenuBar()
        Menu1=Gtk.Menu()
        Mfile=Gtk.MenuItem("_File")
        Mfile.set_submenu(Menu1)
        Clos=Gtk.MenuItem("Close")
        Menu1.append(Clos)
        Clos.connect('button-press-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        Menubar.append(Mfile)
        Box.pack_start(Menubar, expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)


Wind=MenuTest()
Wind.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
Wind.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use the signal "activate" and not "button-press-event".

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!
If you want to convert your comment to an answer i will set it as the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the signal "activate" and not "button-press-event".

The `"button-press-event"` signal comes from the `Gtk.Widget` class which `Gtk.MenuItem` is derived from. This signal is emitted when a button normally from a mouse is pressed. The event mask needs to be set for the widget to receive this signal for this signal it is `Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK`. Normally this signal is not needed.

`Gtk.MenuItem` has the `"activate signal"` which is emitted when an item is activated. This could be by a mouse button as wells as keyboard, touch screen, etc...

Comment: Thank god! Could the Gnome people not think about creating a `clicked` signal just like the "GTK button". They should be more consistent with their API.